# finding multiple values in one column and replace values in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I want to find values in one column and replace values in another column in sheet2.

My data is in sheet1.

How do I find and replace value?

[image: plz check attached image]

I tried the following formula but it is not working.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,Sheet2!B:B,Sheet2!B:B,1)
```

Comment: It's not working because it has no idea which text to select from sheet2

Comment: select first column contain from sheet 1 for find value and find this value in sheets 2 first column and select second column for replace and keep replace value in result column showing as attache image

Comment: Yeah I understand what you want it to do, but it doesn't know how to, given the criteria of SUBSTITUTE.

Answer (score 1):

the SUBSTITUTE() function replaces text in a cell. It does not help in your situation at all.

You seem to want to look up part of a text value that may be nested in another cell. You expect that the position of the search value in the search cell will return a the value of a related value in a target cell. That's quite a big ask.

Well, there is no native Excel function that delivers this result. You may want to find a developer who can write a custom function to do what you need.

Or you may want to find a way to organise the data in one-to-one relationships.

Answer (score 0):

If your Data is the same like in the array Original Text (aaa bbb ccc) not more, Use the following formula
`=IF(LEN(A2)<4,VLOOKUP(A2,sheet2!$E$1:$F$6,2,FALSE),IF(LEN(A2)<7,VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,3),sheet2!$E$1:$F$6,2,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(MID(A2,5,3),sheet2!$E$1:$F$6,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,3),sheet2!$E$1:$F$6,2,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(MID(A2,5,3),sheet2!$E$1:$F$6,2,FALSE)&" "&VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A2,3),sheet2!$E$1:$F$6,2,FALSE)))`
In A2 is the original text, Sheet2!$E$1:$F$6 is the array in sheet2 where you will find the value to replace it, 2 is the second column in sheet2, False to find the exact match in any order.